# Algorithm to optimally fit a sphere between other spheres in a 3D bounding box?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, 3d, volume, packing

I'm struggling with a 3D problem for which I'm trying to find an efficient algorithm.

I have a bounding box with given width, height, and depth.
I also have a list of spheres. That is, a center coordinate (x<sub>i</sub>,y<sub>i</sub>,z<sub>i</sub>) and radius r<sub>i</sub> for each sphere.

The spheres are guaranteed to fit within the bounding box, and to not overlap eachother.

So my situation is like this:

[image: spheres in bounding box]

**Now I have a new sphere with radius r, which I have to fit inside the bounding box, not overlapping any of the previous spheres.**

**I also have a target point T = (x,y,z) and my goal is to fit this new sphere (given the conditions above) as close as possible to this target point.**

I'm trying to construct an efficient algorithm to find an optimal position for the new sphere. Optimal as in: as close to the target point as possible. Or a "false" result if there is no space to fit this new sphere between or around the existing ones anywhere within the bounding box.

I have thought of all sorts of complex approaches, such as building some sort of parametric description of the remaining volume, starting with the bounding box and subtracting the existing spheres one by one. But it doesn't seem to lead me towards a workable solution.

Note that there are a lot of known 'sphere packing' algorithms, but they tend to just fill volumes with random spheres. Also they often use a trial and error approach, just doing a certain amount of random attempts and then terminate.

Whereas I have a given specific new sphere size, and I need to fit that in (or find out that it's not possible).

Comment: Expand all your existing spheres by r and try and place a point in the bounding box that isn't inside any of them. This simplifies the problem somewhat but still doesn't provide an optimal solution.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that's something I also thought about. This reduces the problem to finding a point between a set of spheres. But in this scenario I still don't see how I can efficiently search for a point as close to T as possible.

Comment: After applying @samgak's neat trick, I would use a signed distance function to represent the existing spheres: this is a function that, given an (x, y, z) point, returns a floating point value that gives the distance to the nearest sphere surface, or the negative of this if the point is inside a sphere -- which is literally just the minimum of `EuclideanDistance((cx[i], cy[i], cz[i]), (x, y, z)) - cr[i] - r` over all existing spheres. This can be sped up by only considering "nearby" spheres. Try small steps in several directions, and move in whatever direction increases the function the most.

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach is by computing the "distance map" of the spheres, i.e. the function that returns for every point (x, y, z) the distance to the closest sphere, which is also the distance to the closest center minus the radius of the corresponding sphere. The map is made of the intersection of (hyper)conical surfaces.

Then you can explore the distance map around the target point and find the closest point with a value that exceeds the target radius.

If I am right, the distance map is directly related to the additively weighted Voronoi diagram of the sphere centers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_Voronoi_diagram), and the vertices of the diagram correspond to local maxima. Hence the closest Voronoi vertex with a value that exceeds the target radius will give a solution.

Unfortunately, the construction of this diagram won't be a barrel of laughs. Check the article "Euclidean Voronoi diagram of 3D balls and its computation
via tracing edges" and its bibliography.

---

A possibly workable solution to estimate the distance map is by discretizing space in a regular grid of cubes, and for every cube obtain a lower and an upper bound of the distance function.

For a single given sphere and a given cube, it is possible to find the minimum and maximum value analytically. Then considering all spheres, you can find the smallest maximum and smallest minimum, which are an upper and lower bound of the true distance (the largest minimum won't do). Then you keep all the spheres such that the minimum remains below that upper bound and you get a (hopefully short) list of candidates.

Here you can check the distances to the spheres in the list, and if the upper bound is smaller than the target radius, you can drop the cube. If you find an upper bound above the target radius, you have found a solution.
Otherwise, if the uncertainty range on the distance function is too large, subdivide the cube in smaller ones for a more accurate estimate of the upper and lower bounds.

To obtain a solution close to the target point, you will visit the cubes by increasing distance from the target (using nested digital spheres), until you find a match.

A key point in this process is to quickly find the spheres closest to a given cube, for the initial estimates. A data structure such as a kD-tree or similar might be helpful.